# JavaFX How Can I Center a Tooltip on a Node?

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip, styling

I'm currently working on a form that features validation upon changing focus from one node to another and wish to display a tooltip centered above a node containing an error if one exists. I'm using the tooltip's `show(Node ownerNode, double anchorX, double anchorY)` method signature to specify which node I would like to attach it to and where to position it.

I've tried the following code:

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Error"); 
tooltip.show(node, 0, 0);
double tooltipMiddle = tooltip.getWidth() / 2;
tooltip.hide(); 
double nodeMiddle = node.getWidth() / 2; 

//Gets the node's x and y position within the window
Bounds bounds = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal());  

//Tooltip's bottom-right corner is set to the anchor points, so I set x to
//the node's x coordinate plus half the width of the node plus half the width
//of the tooltip 
tooltip.show(node,
             bounds.getMinX() + nodeMiddle + tooltipMiddle, bounds.getMinY());
```

This has gotten me very close to the center, but it's still off. I've been all over the internet trying to find help, but I'm just not finding any, so I figured I'd ask here.
Any chance I could get some insight into why I'm not able to get this working how I'd like it?

[image: Validation message screenshot]

Comment: bad ux to not allow the user to see her input at all times, valid or not ... that's (probably) why popup.anchorLocation has only sides ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code which I bring provides correct positioning of tooltip but is far from being perfect. It would take a lot of work to bring comprehensive solution (if you want we can discuss it).
Going to the bottom I think you have a math problem and *Tooltip* class may not be the best option.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TooltipApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPrefWidth(100.);

        Button button = new Button("Tooltip");

        HBox hBox = new HBox(textField, button);
        hBox.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        Label label = new Label("Empty!");
        label.setVisible(false);
        Pane tooltipPane = new Pane(label);
        tooltipPane.setMouseTransparent(true);

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(hBox, tooltipPane);
        stackPane.setPrefSize(600., 400.);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (label.isVisible()) {
                label.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                Bounds sceneBounds = textField.localToScene(textField.getBoundsInLocal());
                label.setLayoutX((sceneBounds.getMinX() + (sceneBounds.getWidth() / 2)) - (label.getWidth() / 2));
                label.setLayoutY(sceneBounds.getMinY() - label.getHeight());
                label.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: While your code does position a `Label` correctly, I think it misses the question as applying the same procedure to a `Tooltip` leads to the problem where `getWidth()` seems to be off by a few pixels.

Comment: @floxbr That is why I wrote that Tooltip is not the best fit to solve the problem.

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak Thanks for the response. I'll probably end up using a solution similar to this. I think the problem has to do with the drop shadow of the tooltip itself, causing the calculation of the middle to be off just slightly. I'm going to select this as my answer. Thanks for helping me think differently.

Comment: @MattReichard You're welcome. Always glad to help. Just wanted to add one point. Problem you described is hard to implement because of possible Window size changes which may/should cause "tooltip" (no matter if it's Stage or Pane) position recalculate. Just wanted to bring your attention to this matter.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `Bounds bounds = node.localToScreen(node.getBoundsInLocal());` as it might not be clear what the relevant `Scene` is.

Then calling `tooltip.show(node, bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY());` should give you a tooltip with an upper left corner identical to the upper upper left corner of node.

Now, `tooltip.show(node, bounds.getMinX() + nodeMiddle - tooltipMiddle, bounds.getMinY() - tooltipHeight);` should produce the desired result and it does for

```
double tooltipMiddle = (tooltip.getWidth()-18) / 2;
double tooltipHeight = tooltip.getHeight()-18;
double nodeMiddle = getWidth() / 2;
```

The 18 came from a little experimenting and I'm not sure why the width and height are off by that amount, but it seems to be indpendent of the length or number of lines of the text in the tooltip.